# Scraping across multiple pages using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, threadpoolexecutor

I would need to understand what is not working in iterating the scraping through pages using ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 2050)]
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            f = f.result()
            if f:
                allin.extend(f)
                print("\n", allin)
```

I would like to scrape some information (titles, summaries and dates) across all the pages of a specific link. The code above submits the main faction. I do not get any error in running, but there are news/pages that are missing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get(
        website+"/pag/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    stories = soup.select("div.story-content-pull")
    data = []
    for story in stories:
        row = []
        row.append(story.select_one('a').text)
        row.append(story.select_one('p').text.strip())
        row.append(story.select_one('time').text)
        data.append(row)
        return data
```

If you could let me know what is wrong in the code, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with how you use `ThreadPoolExacutor`. I've cleaned up and simplified your code a bit. Also, there are `2050` pages but you're missing one in your code, as `range()`'s stop value is exclusive.

Try this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(num):
    page = requests.get("https://www.cataniatoday.it/cronaca/pag/{}/".format(num))
    stories = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').select("div.story-content-pull")
    return [
        [
            story.select_one('a').text,
            story.select_one('p').text.strip(),
            story.select_one('time').text,
        ] for story in stories
    ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for result in [executor.submit(main, num) for num in range(1, 2051)]:
            print(result.result())
            # do more stuff here
```

This parses the articles in the order they're on the website. Test it out with a smaller page range, say, `1 - 6`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the code. It still does not collect all the information per page. I selected a small range but I can see that there are some information missing even in the first page. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Could you share an example of what's missing?

Comment: These are some of the data that is scraping:          `Date  
0           stamattina, 11:48  
1         ieri mattina, 09:30  
2   venerdì pomeriggio, 16:06  
3   giovedì pomeriggio, 15:44  
4     mercoledì scorso, 15:20  
5       martedì scorso, 12:12  `, so for example, if you go to page 1, it is missing the most recent news (e.g., circa 4 ore fa), and some other news (e.g., that one stamattina, 11:06, and others)